# node-gyp error when installing sharp

Tags: python, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I was trying to do an `npm install` on a project I moved from another machine and this is what I got

```
Error: Python executable "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.EXE" is v3.6.0, which is not supported by gyp
```

I know there have already been a number of people getting similar errors, but the ones I found were due to outdated Node.js installation. I'm sure the Node.js I got installed is the newest LTS to date. To be exact:

```
node -v v6.10.0
node-gyp -v v3.4.0
npm -v 3.10.10
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes it pretty clear, Python 3 is not supported by gyp, which is used to build node addons. You need Python 2 (e.g. 2.7.x) instead. Additional build requirements for *all* node addons can be found in [the node-gyp readme](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: So, I need to install older Python, then?

Comment: You need to install the latest Python 2 release. Not necessarily *older*. For example, 2.7.13 (the latest 2.x as of this writing) was released on 12/17/2016. The latest 3.x (3.6.0) was released on 12/23/2016.

Comment: Looks like the problem with Python is solved. The thing now complains about `VCBuild.exe` Anyway, your answer is the one I've been looking for, specifically that last comment.